# Is there a way to tell when a document has been synced with the database from the cache?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am building an instant messaging app, akin to WhatsApp, and I need to display the send status of the message: Sending, Sent; sending being if it is the Firebase cache, due to being offline, and sent if the message is on the online database.

Is there a way to tell if a specific document has been uploaded to the database?

I currently have a live update listener listening on the messages collection in firestore that fires when either the cache or database updates. It can tell where the update came from but that returns all of the messages and doesn't specify any individual documents.

Here is a snippet of the completion block for the listener.

```
let source = snapshot.metadata.isFromCache ? "local cache" : "server"

print ("metadata: data fetched from DB: \(source)")

for diff in snapshot.documentChanges {
    print("diffData: \(diff.type.rawValue)")
    print("messageId: \(diff.document.documentID)")
    switch diff.type {
    case .added:
        print("added")
    case .removed:
        print("removed")
    case .modified:
        print("modified")
    }
}

var messages: [ChatEntry] = []
let deletedIds = [String]()
let permanentlyDeletedIds = [String]()

for document in snapshot.documents {
    if document.exists {
         let message = ChatEntry(fromSnapshot: document)
         print("MessageId: \(message?.id ?? "null")")
         print("messageText: \(message?.message ?? "Null")")
    }
}
```

The callback runs when either the cache or DB updates, but if one updates, then the other updates then the document changes is emptied. meaning the I can't tell what happened.

Any advice would be appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find precisely that information in the [`SnapshotMetadata`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/SnapshotMetadata) of a `QuerySnapshot`, which has an [`isFromCache` property](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/SnapshotMetadata#isfromcache) that:

> Returns YES if the snapshot was created from cached data rather than guaranteed up-to-date server data.

You'll want to [listen for metadata changes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#events-metadata-changes) to be able to update the UI once the data is synchronized to the server.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion on this this would be to:

- Set the status to "Sending" when you write a value to Firebase from the client - regardless of if you are online or offline (Firebase already handles this process for you so don't reinvent it).
- Use your existing callback to notify you of new messages matching that one which you can then mark as "Sent" once you receive them (via the callback).

To make this easier you may even want to create a temporary array of ID's that you expect will be coming back from Firebase once written to the Firebase DB.  This will allow you to easily validate that the message sent was the one you expected back.

Let me know if this helps.

Andrew