# How do i know all my changes made to document in offline mode are synced to firestore when i turn on internet in flutter firestore

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating **flutter app**, where I am using **Cloud Firestore** as a database and I am utilizing its offline capability. the app perfectly works when I am in offline mode it saves documents locally and when I turn on the internet it syncs those documents back to Firestore.

I want to know is there any way to know that all of my documents are synced when I turn on the internet, like some event listener or something?

I didn't find anything in the documentation.

Comment: have you checked this https://stackoverflow.com/a/55537824/14139196

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to know if is there any way to know that all of my documents are synced when I turn on the internet, like some event listener or something?

Yes, you can know that in Flutter too. So please check the [SnapshotMetadata](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/SnapshotMetadata-class.html) of a [QuerySnapshot](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/QuerySnapshot-class.html) object, which contains an [isFromCache](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/SnapshotMetadata/isFromCache.html) field that:

> Whether the snapshot was created from cached data rather than guaranteed up-to-date server data.

If your Flutter project requires you to [listen for metadata changes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#dart_2), then please check the official documentation:

> If you want to receive snapshot events when the document or query metadata changes, pass a listen to options object when attaching your listener:

```
final docIdRef = db.collection("collName").doc("docId");
docIdRef.snapshots(includeMetadataChanges: true).listen((event) {
  //Your logic.
});
```

In this way, you'll be able to update the UI elements of your screens, once the data is synchronized with the Firebase servers.

Comment: Hey Jay. Can I help you with other information?

Comment: Yes, Can you tell me how can i check all my documents are synced at collection level, not at individual document level, it would be great help Alex

Comment: If you need to listen to more documents, then you should perform a query. So give it a try. If you however have a hard time implementing it, please post a new question, here on StackOverflow, using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.